# How would you say "let me dream"?

Tags: translation

I was wondering how to say "let me dream" in Japanese ?

My Japanese teacher told me that it could be « ゆめを見たい » but I’m not quite sure that it perfectly transcribes what I meant to say. I have also found « ゆめをみさせて » but again I still have a doubt.

Comment: How do you think you would say it? Unless you indicate your own effort your question will be closed.

Comment: What's the doubt you have about ゆめをみさせて?

Comment: In the first place what *are* you trying to say with 'let me dream'? The answerer seems to have assumed you meant 'let me hold on to my fantasies/aspirations', but it could also mean 'let me sleep', and potentially more things

Answer (score 3):

A common phrase, not a direct translation, is "Don't break my dreams" 夢を壊すな (yume wo kowasu na) or 夢を壊さないでください (yume wo kowasanaide kudasai)